# Center list as width of screen changes

Tags: html, css

i have a unordered list which is of some circular images. The circles are a set width of 350px and float left so that when you zoom the the amount of images on a row changes.
What i wan't is so that if there is a gap to the right of the images (where the images don't fit perfectly with the width) then the images will all centre themselves. I have tried putting auto margins in some places but it doesn't work. I have included some images below to help explain:

[Here is what the images look like when the don't match the width](https://gyazo.com/f27118580147d4fc4e52b9461a31a6e4)

[Here is what i would wan't it to look like (I made this with an image editor)](https://i.gyazo.com/c15902311fa81439374ac31761329660.jpg)

And below is my code for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="gallerydisplay">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://kerivillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/spa.candles.keri_.village.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.faroairporttransfersalgarve.com/app/webroot/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/spa.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.myholidayguru.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/wellness-candles-stones-flowers-spa-748x498.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52291225e4b0af57b790b008/t/522b641fe4b04c838fabf7b1/1378575396909/spa-still-life.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.lemassagerb.com/or-spa-sliderimage.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.pampermetanninganddayspa.com/Spa%20(1).jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.tapatiocliffshilton.com/interactive/top_spa2.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.spa-tara.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/candles1.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.theconistonhotel.com/userfile/spa/couples-massage.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://cologne.regency.hyatt.com/hyatt/images/hotels/colog/spa_signature.jpg.pagespeed.ce.o6UsOTF7Ab.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="https://static.mgmresorts.com/content/dam/MGM/mgm-grand/spa-and-salon/grand-spa-&-health-club/architecture/mgm-grand-amenities-spa-lifestyle-woman-facial-mask-@2x.jpg.image.550.325.high.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.kidayspa.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Spa-Day-Banner2.png" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/23/17/43/relaxation-686392_960_720.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.cadburyhotelbristol.co.uk/assets/media/images/boxes/Spa-Things.gif" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.lcc-transarabiandubai.com/image/static/AE1135/files/-1448431703223/spa.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.omnihotels.com/-/media/images/globals/spa/massage-couples-166668375.jpg?h=660&la=en&w=1170" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.omnihotels.com/-/media/images/globals/spa/honey-144285723.jpg?h=660&la=en&w=1170" height="100%"></div></li>
        <li><div class="circleoutline"><img src="http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/glossary/banana-crop.jpg" height="100%"></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .gallerydisplay
{
    margin-top: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.gallerydisplay ul
{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallerydisplay li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 1%;
    height: 350px;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 0.2vh 0vh 0.8vh #888888;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circleoutline
{
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 2.3%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try to set the li width: 33%;. Otherwise, instead of ul element, use 3-columns Table and set column width to 33%. Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the li elements to display inline-block, and remove the float left. Because your ordered list is styled with Text Align Center, the li will center inside of it. Your css will become:

```
.gallerydisplay ul{
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallerydisplay li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 350px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0.2vh 0vh 0.8vh #888888;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: [Worked perfectly! Thankyou](https://i.gyazo.com/e2c913996f9e01c989b2fe0e6bbdb9e6.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is using `float:left` for `.gallerydisplay li` class. Please use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`.

```
.gallerydisplay li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 1%;
    height: 350px;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 0.2vh 0vh 0.8vh #888888;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or You can use the media queries for a specific resolution range like the code below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
   .gallerydisplay li:first-child {
     margin-left: 10px;
   }    
}
```

and add `margin-left` to the first child. However, the responsive solution is giving the widths as percentage to the images.

PS. You can use bootstrap to solve this problem easily with the grid system. Here is the link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid